# Updating NVD3 /D3 chart as per user input radio button

Tags: angularjs, d3.js, angularjs-directive, nvd3.js

http://nvd3.org/examples/cumulativeLine.html

This example show 4 lines chart. What i want to achieve below.

currently, Series 1, Series 2, Series 3, Series 4 (Charts and Respective legends)

I want keep Series 1, Series 2, Series 3 as common

and I have few radio buttons(Outside chart Area) like Series 5, Series 6, Series 7 and on and on.

Now clicking on those radio button i want to show respective chart and common charts(in this case series 1 ,2 and 3)

for Example
Series 5 radio button clicked
Now Series 1, Series 2, Series 3, Series 5 is shown, [This would removed chart3 legend-chart and add legend-chart of Series 5].

I am trying to achieve above in AngularJS and NVD3 Directive. But i am ok i am known to D3 code logic i should be able to change to angular way. Providing Angular work around is warm welcomed.

[Update]

Strange, instead of cumulative i used simple line chart. I changed the data and chart is being updated as anticipated. I dont what is wrong with cumulative. Any Idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With angularjs you can try [angular-nvd3](http://krispo.github.io/angular-nvd3/) directive. It allows you to manipulate with chart data and chart options via JSON, like:

```
//html
<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>

//javascript
$scope.options = { /*some options*/ }
$scope.data = [ /*some data*/ ]
```

So, in your case, we just extend this approach to when we interactively update data. We can write something like (using checkboxes):

```
//html
<div ng-repeat="series in initData">
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="checkboxes[series.key]" ng-init="checkboxes[series.key]=true" ng-change="onchange()"/>{{series.key}}
</div>
<nvd3 options="options" data="data"></nvd3>
```

where `initData` is a whole static dataset. And in controller

```
//javascript
$scope.options = { /*some options*/ }
$scope.initData = [
        {
            key: "Long",
            mean: 250,
            values: [ ... ]
        }, 
        ...
];
$scope.data = angular.copy($scope.initData);        
$scope.checkboxes = {};        
$scope.onchange = function(){
    $scope.data = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.initData, function(value, index){
        if ($scope.checkboxes[value.key]) $scope.data.push(value);
    })
}
```

See live example: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLcS6M?p=preview

Comment: First of all, congratulations for this fantastic framework..really useful...Actually, the plunkr is not working properly. I think, it is because it is missing a style..bye

Comment: It's because the lib referred to master branch. I've changed it to the relevant version. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Note: angular-nvd3

http://embed.plnkr.co/tsJntqq5YJnNUGK6goLZ/preview

See plunkr, I did for a button adding a new serie so it shouldn't have too different just changing for the radio. Notice that if you are getting the data from Web Services or similar resources you probably have to redraw the graph

See https://github.com/krispo/angular-nvd3/issues/37

In the directive

    `<nvd3 options="options" data="data" api="api"></nvd3>`

In the Controller

    `$scope.api.refresh();`

Hope this help

Comment: $scope.api.refresh(); is not working for me...
api seems to be undefined... Any idea why?